# Power BI Desktop - Number format - shows american format in visuals but European everywhere else

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have created a report in Power BI Desktop. It is not linked to Service.

When i created the report i set the regional settings (local file) to danish, so the number and date format would be correct, but for some reason the format is only correct in the query editor and data view. When I create a visual (table), it shows the numberformat as an american format.

I have Windows 10 on my computer, if that can affect the problem somehow. My regional settings in windows is set to danish as well.

Datasource is an azure sql-server database.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance

EDIT - SOLUTION:
It was the Windows region settings making the mess. 
It was set to "English (Denmark)" before and after I changed it to "Danish (Denmark)" PBI Desktop formatted correctly after a restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the worst features of Power BI, and also undocumented, so you are right to be confused.

You can do this using the Model view (left nav).  Select the field(s) in the FIELDS pane and choose **PROPERTIES / Format = Currency** then choose **PROPERTIES / Currency format = Danish (Denmark)**.

You also do this "old way" from the Modeling ribbon: select your field (one at a time) in the FIELDS pane (left click), then set the Format = Currency / Danish (Denmark).

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I have tried both of your solutions, and unfortunately they didn't seem to work. After i applied the changes i saved the document and reopened with no change.

Besides the numbers is in different currencies and the DKK/kr. in the field would create confusion for the user. I also have a qty field that is formatted in the american format.

I have tried to use DAX FORMAT(), which kinda works, but ruins the aggregation and totals.
All i'm trying to achieve is having the dot for thousand separator and the comma for the decimals. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes its a steaming mess. I don't recommend FORMAT. I suspect the issue is buried in your Windows regional settings.

Comment: I solved it. 
It was the Windows region settings making the mess. It was "English (Denmark)" before and after I changed it to "Danish (Denmark)" PBI Desktop formatted correctly after a restart. Thank you a lot :)